# how to calculate mean from part or a list/matrix/dataframe ? and which data type is fastest to do it?

Tags: r

I have this matrix (may it be other similar data type) with two columns x and y and I want for each x calculate the mean of all values from y corresponding to this particular x (Of course when there are more than one x with particular value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ave` or `aggregate`, depending on how you want the output.

A `matrix` will be faster than a `data.frame`, but you can only use a `matrix` if `x` and `y` are the same type.

```
set.seed(21)
x <- cbind(rnorm(20), sample(1:2,20,TRUE))
ave(x[,1], x[,2])
aggregate(x[,1], by=list(x[,2]), FUN=mean)
```

Comment: thank you, in my case: ave(data[,'Y'],data[,'X'], FUN=mean) is doing the trick, that is columns in function are in reverse order as they would be probably in tables